# QFileDialog close on OK button activation

Tags: qt, pyqt4

I am using pyqt4 and windows. I have an application where I select a directory using QFileDialog. After the directory is selected, I want to close the file dialog when the user selects the OK button of the file dialog. The behavior desired should be the same as the behavior of the cancel button. How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: You'd need `QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory` static method. I don't know its syntax in Python though.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory()` static method.

```
 dir = QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self);
```